# Saltstack variables

Tags: python, variables, salt-stack

I have the question about variables in salt.
I am trying to use the if statements to create more complex states with salt.

example working:

```
{% set old_stable = salt['cmd.run']('cd /home/project_name && ls -t|grep 2|grep -v tar.gz|tail -n +2|head -n 1') %}
{% set time_date = salt['cmd.run']('date +%Y%m%d%H%M') %}
{% if salt['cmd.run']('ls -lt /home/project_name/ | wc -l') == 2 %}
      <STATE>
{% endif  %}
```

So, the question is:
Can I define "/home/project_name/" like variable like {{ old_stable }}to put on top of file

Inserting of variable in if statement doesn't work

example(not working)

```
{% set project = '/home/project_name' %}
 {% if salt['cmd.run']('ls -lt {{ project }}') | wc -l') == 2 %}
       <STATE>
 {% endif  %}
```

My code is

```
{% set project = 'test_web_tool' %}

{% if salt['cmd.run']('ls -lt /home/project-user/project 2>/dev/null| wc -l') != "0" %}

output:
 cmd.run:
     - names:
       - echo "Rollback directory {{ project }}"
     - cwd: /root

{% else %}

error_output:
 cmd.run:
     - names:
       - echo "This is the last directory. Cant remove it"
    - cwd: /root

{% endif  %}
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to use [`~` operator](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#other-operators) to concatenate two strings:

```
{% set project = '/home/project_name' %}
{% if salt['cmd.run']('ls -lt ' ~ project ~ ' | wc -l') == 2 %}
    <STATE>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [jinja documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#variables):

> It’s important to know that the curly braces are not part of the variable but the print statement. If you access variables inside tags don’t put the braces around.

So to get your not working example to be working you would need to do remove the curly brace as shown below:

```
{% set project = '/home/project_name' %}
{% if salt['cmd.run']('ls -lt project') | wc -l') == 2 %}
       <STATE>
{% endif  %}
```

Comment: That sounds like an issue later you in your salt template file. Can you post the whole thing?

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work it returns always true :(
may be there are debugging tool to see what going wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately the inability to see how the jinja will be interpreted is one of the pain points for using salt-stack right now. I think the problem is that we seem to be thinking that jinja works like bash when it doesn't. Would you mind seeing a pure python solution for this or does it have to be in jinja?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're code snippet is wrong in the way that you have't taken care of the single apostrophe's. Notice you have one less.

```
{% set project = '/home/project_name' %}
{% if salt['cmd.run']('ls -lt {{ project }}') | wc -l') == 2 %}
   <STATE>
{% endif  %}
```

This is the correct version as far as the single apostrophe goes:

```
{% set project = '/home/project_name' %}
{% if salt['cmd.run']('ls -lt {{ project }}) | wc -l') == 2 %}
   <STATE>
{% endif  %}
```

Secondly, concatenate the variable value with the command by using ~ operator that concatenates two strings.

Here's what i found about the ~ operator on Jinja 2 2.7.2 documentation:

```
~
Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them. {{ "Hello " ~ name ~ "!" }} 
would return (assuming name is 'John') Hello John!.
```

So here's the final correct version:

```
{% set project = '/home/project_name' %}
{% if salt['cmd.run']('ls -lt' ~ project ~ ') | wc -l') == 2 %}
   <STATE>
{% endif  %}
```